# How do I get a pod's (milli)core CPU usage with Prometheus in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I run a `v1.9.2` custom setup of Kubernetes and scrape various metrics with Prometheus `v2.1.0`. Among others, I scrape the `kubelet` and `cAdvisor` metrics.

I want to answer the question: "*How much of the CPU resources defined by `requests` and `limits` in my deployment are actually used by a pod (and its containers) in terms of (milli)cores?*"

There are a lot of scraped metrics available, but nothing like that. Maybe it could be calculated by the CPU usage time in seconds, but I don't know how.

I was considering it's not possible - until a friend told me she runs Heapster in her cluster which has a graph in the built-in Grafana that tells *exactly* that: It shows the indivual CPU usage of a pod and its containers in (milli)cores.

Since Heapster also uses `kubelet` and `cAdvisor` metrics, I wonder: how can I calculate the same? The metric in InfluxDB is named `cpu/usage_rate` but even with Heapster's code, I couldn't figure out how they calculate it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We're using the `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metric to calculate Pod CPU usage. This metrics contains the total amount of CPU seconds consumed *by container by core* (this is important, as a Pod may consist of multiple containers, each of which can be scheduled across multiple cores; however, the metric has a `pod_name` annotation that we can use for aggregation). Of special interest is the **change rate** of that metric (which can be calculated with [PromQL's `rate()` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate())). If it increases by 1 within one second, the Pod consumes 1 CPU core (or 1000 milli-cores) in that second.

The following PromQL query does just that: Compute the CPU usage of all Pods (using the [`sum(...) by (pod_name)`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) operation) over a five minute average:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])) by (pod_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a StackOverflow question and answer with exactly your query, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Alex _"this is not what I am looking for"_ Sorry to hear that. What _are_ you looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I might get you wrong. So after firing the query, I get a value like 1.4757899821777767. You said this is equivalent to ~1470 millicores. Is there some resource for me to check that might help me understand that relation?

Comment: Basically, cores and millicores are nothing else than an abstraction on CPU utilization. A CPU consumption of "1 core" (~1000 millicores) means that a Pod utilizes one CPU core by 100% (500 millicores means 50% and so on); CPU _limits_ work the same: For example, a limit of 250 millicores means that a Pod may utilize one CPU core by not more than 25%. Have a look at [the _"Managing Compute Resources for Containers"_ section in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-cpu) for more information.

Comment: I don't see how _container_cpu_usage_seconds_total_ which should give how many seconds the CPU is used represents what question asks for - CPU utilization _in terms of (milli)cores_. If I have _container_cpu_usage_seconds_total_ equals to 100ms (milliseconds) how to calculate how many millicores is that?

Comment: @VentzyKunev The value of total CPU usage of 100ms is -- by itself -- not particularly meaningful. It DOES become useful if you know that your Pod used 100ms of CPU time _per second_ -- which is exactly what Prometheus's `rate` function does. The rest is just conversion between different units. A usage of 100ms of CPU time per 1000ms of _real time_ corresponds to a CPU usage of 10% (within that one second) -- or, alternatively of 1/10 CPU core (or 100 millicores).

Comment: @helmbert Shouldn't we take the average, instead of sum, if there are multiple cores to get the CPU utilization? Because as I see it, there is a `cpu` label in `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` which specifies usage per each core?!

Comment: @today You can do both, depending on what question you want your query to answer. When taking the average, you'll get your Pod's _average utilization per core per second_ (an information of arguable usefulness, since the knowing your number of cores is important for interpreting this value -- an avg utilization of ".5 on one core" is wildly different than ".5 on 64 cores"). Using `sum`, you'll get your Pod's _total utilization across all cores per second_ (with a value like ".5" if you've utilized one core by 50% or two by 25% or like "32" if you've utilized 64 cores by 50%). Hope that helps!

Comment: @helmbert Thank you for your reply. You are right. Basically, the value given by `avg` is normalized by the number of cores, whereas `sum` is not. So I think if we want an overall estimate of CPU utilization (i.e. CPU usage percentage) then the `avg` would be a better choice; however, if we are interested to find the overall utilization of cores (i.e. how many cores are being utilized overall), then the `sum` would be a better choice.

Comment: Many thanks, I've been looking for this particular query for awhile. And the _explanation_ is really helpful. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following PromQL query returns per-pod number of used CPU cores starting from Kubernetes v1.16 and newer versions:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (pod)
```

The `{container!=""}` filter is needed for filtering out cgroups hierarchical stats, which is already included into per-container stats. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for more details on this.

The following PromQL query must be used for Kubernetes below v1.16 because it uses different label names (e.g. `container_name` instead of `container` and `pod_name` instead of `pod` - see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1206) for details):

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!=""}[5m])) by (pod_name)
```